# Build electron como http server

Tags: javascript, electron

Gostaria de saber se há alguma possibilidade de compilar o Electron e o Executavel abrir os arquivos como HTTP server ao invés de executá-los como file:// estou tentando acessar uma pagina na web que não aceita request de domínios file:// então preciso que o meu .EXE execute os arquivos como http:// é possivel fazer uma compilação do electron como se ele estivesse executando em Dev ?

Comment: Tem Node.js? Podias montar um servidor simple com Node. Mais simples.

Comment: Preciso que seja via electron pq montar servidor node no usuario na hora de executar daria mto trabalho.

Comment: @Sergio O electron tem o Node embutido. É simplesmente questão de iniciar um servidor, e o outro lado do electron acessar. Gabriel, que eu saiba o electron não restringe o protocolo a `file://`, pode usar `http://` se isso apontar para um recursos existente (seja servido pelo node interno do electron, seja um site externo mesmo).

Comment: @bfavaretto interessante, uso o eletron para testes end-to-end, mas nunca usei sozinho assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto então, no caso os arquivos estão compilados em um .asar e na hora que vou rodar o EXE gerado pelo packer ele acessa os arquivos como file:// e como não queria que o Electron acessasse um node externo na web (para evitar custo de servidor) queria saber se consigo executar o ambiente de dev do electron (geralmente cria-se um http server) em produção.